# Java Script OOP setting Object Key name and accessing Key name and values in methods

Tags: javascript, oop, csx

```
function Inventory(item, price){
  const newObj = {};
        this.item = {
        price: price,
        quantity: 1,
      };

/*I tried this too 
  [item] = {
        price: price,
        quantity: 1,
      };
      */
}


  Inventory.prototype.addItem = function(item, price){
    if(item !== this.item){
      const newInv = new Inventory(item,price);
      return newInv;
  
    }else{
      this.item.quantity++;
      this.item.price = price;
    }
  };
```

I am working through CSX OOP and I have been stuck for a few days now. I am trying to set the objects key name in the constructor based off the input argument item and then have an object inside that key value. But with `this.item` it just displays item. So i tried to make a new object and set it to `newObj[item]` that worked. But when I did this I can not longer access the other keys inside the value of `newObj[item]`.
When its this.item i can access the object inside the value but then the key of item never changes with my arugments.

In short, I need to be able to change the key name based off the arguments and then later access that key name. and I cannot figure out how to do this. Please help

Comment: It's really unclear what your asking here, but looking at the code it seems a little bit confusing, something called `Inventory` I would expect multiple items, eg. an array of items, and when you call the add I would expect that to look at the array etc.

Comment: I am making creating an object in the constructor and the key name needs to be the item argument in Inventory. The key value of item contains two key-value pairs, price: set to the price argument and quantity starting at 1. Then in the add method I am adding a new Inventory if the passed in item(in addItem) has not already been created.

Answer (score -1):

// try bellow logic

newObject = []; // creating empty array to store elements

item = {}; // creating empty item object

item.price = <>;
item.quantity = <>;

newObject.push(item); // storing/pushing item in newObject array